# logfile - Gurobi Python

Tags: python-3.x, logfile, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi in Python interface to solve an integer program. I don't want to see the log file in my console, but I want it to be printed  in a separate text file. I tried doing the following:

```
# Turn off display 

setParam('OutputFlag', 0)

# Create a new model
m = Model("mip1")

# Open log file

logfile = open('mip1 %s.log' %(n), 'w')

m._logfile = logfile
```

Then I have my model details and at the end of the code I'm closing the logfile with `logfile.close()`. But what I could see is that the logfile with the specific formatting has created and its empty(nothing printed). What should I do to get everything printed in my logfile but not in my console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parameter LogToConsole to 0: `setParam("LogToConsole", 0)`

Comment: Thanks Gregg! By doing this,will I be able to create different Logfiles at different runs? For example, when I run the code for 30 points I need a logfile named as "log for 30 points.log" and when running the code for 50 points, I need it to be "log for 50 points.log" .

Comment: Hi, @ccc. I think you can try ```model.setParam("LogFile", log_file)```